# Desktop hard drive won't spin down according to settings

Tags: hard-drive, power-management

I have a desktop machine with two SSDs, one each with Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 13.10, and one HDD which contains a single NTFS partition on which I throw big files. It actually only rarely gets used and so I'd rather it remain off most of the time, as it is the loudest component in my desktop, and I'm not even the slightest bit concerned about long-term wear (I'll replace it before it gets to that point.)

So, I've used the Gnome-Disks utility to set it to standby after 5 minutes:

[image]

However, my drive appears to ignore this and remains on in perpetuity. Automatic spin-down works in Windows 8, and I'm able to use gnome-disks to manually spin down the drive as well, so I don't suspect incompatibility, but is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gnome-disk-utility is broken in this regard.  You can manually set the timer with `sudo hdparm -S 60 /dev/sda`, or you can just manually put it to sleep when you are done using it with `sudo hdparm -y /dev/sda`.

See [bug #1281588](http://launchpad.net/bugs/1281588).  I will prepare a fix and if you could test and verity that it works that would be helpful.

Comment: Looking forward to it. FWIW to anyone who finds this later on, the command for sleeping a drive uses a capital Y.

Comment: @sigmabeta, the lower case y is for standby.  Theoretically sleep saves a tiny bit more power, but udisks brings the drive out of sleep back to standby anyhow when it tries to update the SMART status every 10 minutes.

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that, & thanks for the info.

Comment: @sigmabeta, ok, the package is up in my ppa if you want to test it.

Comment: I've installed all updated packages from your PPA, rebooted, and used the gnome-disks utility to lower the time out to 2min, and it appears to still not work automatically.

Comment: @sigmabeta, most drives won't accept a time less than 5 minutes, so try using that setting.

Comment: with a timeout of 5:30 the drive remains active/idle